# Which music tracks have been remastered for the HD remake?

Tags: final-fantasy-10

For the HD remake of FFX/FFX-2, [over 60 tracks have been remastered or rearranged](http://blog.us.playstation.com/2013/08/23/the-remastered-music-of-final-fantasy-x-hd/). In at least one case, a song in the original game was replaced by [the re-arranged version from the FFX Piano Collections album](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KD-j4jBFt4w).

Is there a full list of new tracks available somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

After 2 years, I would assume that somebody somewhere would have generated a list comparing the original vs remastered track. Unfortunately I looked and was unsuccessful

I wrote a little script to compare the track lists on  [Final Fantasy X HD Remaster Original Soundtrack](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Final_Fantasy_X_HD_Remaster_Original_Soundtrack) and [Final Fantasy X Original Soundtrack](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Final_Fantasy_X:_Original_Soundtrack) and I have generate a list comparing the Original OST and the Remastered OST

> 1. Listen to My Story => I Want To Tell You Everything
> 2. **Zanarkand => Zanarkand (Arranged)**
> 3. **Prelude => Prelude (Arranged)**
> 4. **Tidus's Theme => Tidus's Theme (Arranged)**
> 5. Otherworld => Otherworld
> 6. **Run => Run!! (Arranged)**
> 7. **This Is Your Story => This Is Your Story (Arranged)**
> 8. **Creep => Creep (Arranged)**
> 9. **Battle Theme => Battle Theme (Arranged)**
> 10. **Victory Fanfare => Victory Fanfare (Arranged)**
> 11. **Game Over => Game Over (Arranged)**
> 12. **Out of the Frying Pan => Out Of The Frying Pan (Arranged)**
> 13. **Leap in the Dark => Leap In The Dark (Arranged)**
> 14. **Underwater Ruins => Underwater Ruins (Arranged)**
> 15. **Oui are Al Bhed => Oui Are Al Bhed (Arranged)**
> 16. **Enemy Attack => Enemy Attack (Arranged)**
> 17. **The Blitzers => The Blitzers (Arranged)**
> 18. **Besaid => Besaid (Arranged)**
> 19. **Spira Unplugged => Spira Unplugged (Arranged)**
> 20. Hymn of the Fayth => Hymn of the Fayth
> 21. **Phantoms => Phantoms (Arranged)**
> 22. The Trials => The Trials
> 23. Hymn of the Fayth - Valefor => Hymn - Valefor
> 24. **The Summoning => The Summoning (Arranged)**
> 25. Braska's Daughter => Braska's Daughter
> 26. **Good Night => Good Night (Arranged)**
> 27. **Yuna's Theme => Yuna's Theme (Arranged)**
> 28. **Movement in Green => Movement In Green (Arranged)**
> 29. The Sending => The Sending
> 30. **Calm Before the Storm => Calm Before The Storm (Arranged)**
> 31. Hymn of the Fayth - Ifrit => Hymn - Ifrit
> 32. **Luca => Luca (Arranged)**
> 33. **Grand Maester Mika => Grand Maester Mika (Arranged)**
> 34. **Decision on the Dock => Decision On The Dock (Arranged)**
> 35. The Splendid Performance => The Splendid Performance
> 36. **Face-Off => Face Off (Arranged)**
> 37. **Blitz Off => Blitz Off! (Arranged)**
> 38. **Auron's Theme => Auron's Theme (Arranged)**
> 39. **Mi'ihen Highroad => Mi'ihen Highroad (Arranged)**
> 40. **Chocobo Jam => Chocobo Jam (Arranged)**
> 41. **The Travel Agency => The Travel Agency (Arranged)**
> 42. **They May Pass => They May Pass (Arranged)**
> 43. **Seymour's Theme => Seymour's Theme (Arranged)**
> 44. **Twilight => Twilight (Arranged)**
> 45. Djose Temple => Djose Temple
> 46. Hymn of the Fayth - Ixion => Hymn - Ixion
> 47. Rides Ze Shoopuf? => Ridess The Shoopuf?
> 48. **Rikku's Theme => Rikku's Theme (Arranged)**
> 49. **Guadosalam => Guadosalam (Arranged)**
> 50. **Thunder Plains => Thunder Plains (Arranged)**
> 51. **Jecht's Theme => Jecht's Theme (Arranged)**
> 52. Macalania Woods => Macalania Woods
> 53. **The Void => The Void (Arranged)**
> 54. **The Temple Player => The Temple Players (Arranged)**
> 55. **Seymour's Ambition => Seymour's Ambition (Arranged)**
> 56. Hymn of the Fayth - Shiva => Hymn - Shiva
> 57. **Pursuit => Pursuit (Arranged)**
> 58. **The Burning Sands => The Burning Sands (Arranged)**
> 59. Peril => Peril
> 60. **The Truth Revealed => The Truth Revealed (Arranged)**
> 61. **Launch => Launch (Arranged)**
> 62. **The Wedding => The Wedding (Arranged)**
> 63. **Assault => Assault (Arranged)**
> 64. **Tragedy => Tragedy (Arranged)**
> 65. **Believe => Believe (Arranged)**
> 66. Via Purifico => Via Purifico
> 67. Hymn of the Fayth - Bahamut => Hymn - Bahamut
> 68. Moment of Truth => Moment Of Truth
> 69. Patricide => Patricide
> 70. Suteki Da Ne (Isn't It Wonderful?) => SUTEKI DA NE (Isn't It Wonderful?)
> 71. **Yuna's Decision => Yuna's Decision (Arranged)**
> 72. Lulu's Theme => Lulu's Theme
> 73. Bravely Forward => Bravely Forward
> 74. Hymn of the Fayth - Yojimbo => Hymn - Yojimbo
> 75. **Servants of the Mountain => Servants of the Mountain (Arranged)**
> 76. Hymn of the Fayth - The Ronso => Hymn - The Ronso
> 77. **Wandering => Wandering (Arranged)**
> 78. **A Fleeting Dream => A Fleeting Dream (Arranged)**
> 79. Hymn of the Fayth - Yunalesca => Hymn - Yunalesca
> 80. **Challenge => Challenge (Arranged)**
> 81. Beyond the Darkness => Beyond The Darkness
> 82. **Gloom => Gloom (Arranged)**
> 83. Hymn of the Fayth - Spira => Hymn - Spira
> 84. **The Unsent Laugh => The Unsent Laugh (Arranged)**
> 85. **Fight With Seymour => Fight With Seymour (Arranged)**
> 86. Hymn of the Fayth - Anima => Hymn - Anima
> 87. **A Contest of Aeons => A Contest Of Aeons (Arranged)**
> 88. **Final Battle => Final Battle  (Arranged)**
> 89. Ending Theme => Ending Theme" (Ending Theme)
> 90. Never Forget Them => Please Remember
> 91. Suteki Da Ne (Isn't It Wonderful?) Orchestra Version => SUTEKI DA NE (Isn't It Wonderful?) Orchestra Version

Answer (score -1):

There is some information on track changes here (sadly not much though) - http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Final_Fantasy_X/X-2_HD_Remaster

Looks like the main ones are the battle theme and the thunder plains tracks. "Wakka's Theme" is a newly added track as well.

If I can find an actual list for you somewhere, I'll add it in here!